# Remove bottom border of tab group

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to remove the bottom border of the tabs group which in the image below is gray.

[image]

Here is a sample project to show of the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-remove-bottom-border

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code in this case! I was looking for a solution that i did not have any code to show for. I just added a sample project to show of the code that Julien provided. I did not get it to work though, any toughs why its not responding?

Comment: <mat-tab-group [color]=" 'white' "... if need more https://stackblitz.com/angular/mnoqveldkmm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-theme-example.ts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The border can be found on the `.mat-tab-header` class.

In your main.css file (or main.scss, styles.css or styles.scss), you can globally define

```css
.remove-border-bottom .mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

And in your HTML file, give the `mat-tab-group` a class.

```html
<mat-tab-group class="remove-border-bottom">
    <!-- ... -->
</mat-tab-group>
```

Due to encapsulation, if you want to define the style in your component.scss file, you have to use `::ng-deep`:

```css
.remove-border-bottom ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I put up a code sample with your solution but i cant get that border to go away. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post a stackblitz please?

Comment: The stackblitz link is in my original post now as i updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Add `color="transparent"` to `mat-tab-group`.

Without color property:

[image]

Here's the result with the the color property:

[image]

Like this:

```
  <mat-tab-group color="transparent">
```

[Reference to the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup)

Answer (score 3):

Use this and choose color of your bg :

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color: white; // add styles properties here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular Material 15+, the class name is `mdc-tab-indicator`.

HTML

```
 <mat-tab-group class="no-active-tab-indicator">
    ...
 </mat-tab-group>
```

CSS

```
.no-active-tab-indicator .mdc-tab-indicator{
   display:none 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in my components.scss file I just wrote this to change the color of the border

```css
::ng-deep {
  .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
    border-color: red!important;
  }
}
```

or you can use display: none to remove the border

```css
::ng-deep {
  .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: doesnt work....